# is there a way to use windows form on linux in C++ (Closed)

Tags: c#, c++

sorry for this weird question, but since windows basically shuts down I have since moved to Ubuntu. and on windows, in visual studio I would use windows forms for blank windows and button and such.I found out how to do that in C# but well...  I am not good at all with C# and don't
feel like spending hours of learning C# functions and syntax.

so my question is this. is there any way to use windows forms in C++?

it also might be important to know that I am using mono for C#, but mono doesn't seem to be compatible with C++

P.S.  my C# code is below if you need it to help me.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Window
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Form menu = new Form();
        Form lvl1 = new Form();
        Form options = new Form();
         Button optionsButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Options",
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point (850, 700)
        };
        optionsButton.Click += (o, s) =>
        {
            
            options.Show();
            
        };
        Button quitButton = new Button()

        {
            Text = "Quit",
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(850, 900)
            

        };
        quitButton.Click += (o, s) =>
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Application will now close");
            Application.Exit();
        };

        Button startButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Start!",
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(850, 500)
        };
        startButton.Click += (o, s) =>
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Game Started. Have Fun!!!!");
            lvl1.Show(); 
            startButton.Hide();
            quitButton.Hide();
            optionsButton.Hide();
        };

       

        

      
      
     
    

       


        menu.Controls.Add(startButton);
        menu.Controls.Add(quitButton);
        menu.Controls.Add(optionsButton);
        menu.ShowDialog();
        startButton.AutoSize = true;
        
        
        }
    }

   

     
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Even in the cross-platform .NET Core / .NET 5, WinForms is only available on Windows.

Comment: You may be interested in [Platform independent GUI libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using GTK, since that is similar to what C# is using in my code here, as far as I have researched.

Comment: why do you ask about C++ then post code in C#? But if you're using .NET Core then have a look at [.NET Multi-platform App UI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/)

Comment: The reason why I ask about C++ then post code in C#, I wanted to give you an idea of what I was trying to do.

Comment: "since windows basically shuts down" care to elaborate on that one please?

Comment: older computer. not a problem anymore lol. I bit the bullet and got an older workstation.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I decided I am going to just continue learning C# until I get my new Windows PC. thanks for all the answers.